# Iterate though member variables of struct in C++

Tags: c++, loops, struct, foreach, iteration

I have a struct like this one:

```
struct Player {
POINT3D headPosition;
POINT3D position;
POINT2D view;
INT32 health;
// etc...
};
```

And I would like to iterate through the members of this struct to do some actions, a bit like we could do with *foreach* in some other languages.

Is there any way I could do something like that in C++? My research indicate that it is not possible natively, I found that it could be possible with some library like [Boost.Hana](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/index.html#tutorial-introspection-adapting), but I would like to be sure first that there is absolutely no other ways without a third party library. Even something with macros or generated at compilation time would do. Since we know exactly the struct it has to be automatable somehow. You can ignore the problems related to different data types for my issue, in the "foreach" loop I will give the member variable to a template function that accepts all types of variables found in that struct.

Thank you for your help on this matter.

Comment: No native reflection in C++, you have to rely on some external library asboost hana.

Comment: There is currently no way to natively iterate over the members of a struct. There are some proposals for metaclasses that would support this feature, but currently it is not possible without some meta information about your struct. (Look at Qt or the like).

Comment: https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get might kelp.

Comment: Boost.Hana is a header-only library for C++. The duplicate refers to another Boost reflection solution. Something from Boost is your best option.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible, using insane Russian hacks :-)

The relevant library is Antony Polukhin ["magic get"](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get). Specifically, it offers a "for each field" [mechanism](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get/blob/develop/test/precise/for_each_field.cpp), which takes a templated lambda with auto parameter type. Example:

```
struct simple {
    int a;
    char b;
    short d;
};

simple x {42, 'a', 3};
std::stringstream ss;

boost::pfr::for_each_field(
    x,
    [&ss](auto&& val) {
        ss << val << ' ';
    }
);
```

Caveat: This requires C++14 or even C++17 to work!

Comment: you can also write a genuine struct iterator with that library.

Comment: @user1095108: It wouldn't be a "genuine" iterator, because an iterator has to have a single value type, but sort of, yes.

Comment: well, I needed it, so [here](https://github.com/user1095108/generic/blob/master/structiterator.hpp) it is. It could be made more generic, if some kind of a reference wrapper were used.